Are there theoretical reasons to believe $H_{1}:=\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}p_{n+1}-p_{n}$ should be a highly composite integer?
This question is a follow-up to Difference of prime powers as linear combination of jumping champions and especially to the last edit to date. The jumping champion conjecture states that jumping champions are the primorials and $4$, which make good a priori candidates for $H_{1}$ as a prime gap occurring infinitely often is very likely the most frequent in some range. It appears that the smallest three of these numbers, namely $2$, $4$ and $6$, are highly composite integers, and so is $12$, which is the best upper bound on $H_{1}$ proven to follow from the widely believed Elliott-Halberstam conjecture (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott%E2%80%93Halberstam_conjecture). Terry Tao in his blog states current technology prevents to get under $4$ due to a technical obstacle in sieve theory known as the parity barrier.
On the other hand, the very definition of $H_{1}$ as an infimum suggests it may be
the result of a gradient descent applied
to a relation $F(J_{i},p_{i})$ between
jumping champions and primes as exposed in the link above, so that $H_{1}$ may turn out to be invariant under the substitution $J_{i}\leftrightarrow p_{i}$ leading to $H_{1}\in\{2,4\}$.
So, is $H_{1}$ a highly composite integer?

Can you include a definition of $H_1$ to make this question self-contained?

It's in the title...

It is not entirely clear whether your $p_i$ are primes or powers of primes.  The other question talks a lot about powers of primes.  Also, you may want to include a link for Elliott-Halberstam.

$p_{i}$ denotes the $i$-th prime.
